# css3 rule hide text after i element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I try to get the text removed (in this case it is the text Home, but can be a various text)

```
<div class=" header-links ">
<!-- Ul Starts -->
<ul class=" nav navbar-nav pull-left ">
    <li class=" test "><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- ul Ends -->
```

For it i want to use the dirty trick: `font-size:0px;`

Via the following ( failing sample ) css rule:

```
@media (max-width:767px) {
.header-links li a i {
    font-size:0px;
    }
}
```

In the failing it hides the fontawesome icon, but i want to keep the icon, and only hide the text.

**I am aware that in theory i should do:**

```
    <div class=" header-links ">
<!-- Ul Starts -->
<ul class=" nav navbar-nav pull-left ">
    <li class=" test "><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Home</span></a></li>
</ul>
<!-- ul Ends -->
```

But in my case this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.header-links li a {
    font-size: 0px;
}
.header-links li a i {
    font-size: 12px; /* or whatever */
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/758urk7k/)

Here I'm simply setting the font size on the anchor, and then overriding that for the more specific `i` selector inside it.

Comment: Updated with a better fiddle.

Comment: yes very good Haha, i thought i used common sense by thinking need only 1 rule.But yes this suits.

Comment: just tested with a secondary li element. i expected next icon would show up where `Home` ends and had to enhance more css, but no... it works excellent.Icons are nicely positioned next to each-other, as how i want it.